# Make Custom Camera look full screen android

Tags: android, camera, fullscreen

**What I have**

I a have a `Custom Camera` that uses only `rear camera hardware` **no selfies :)**

**My problem**

My Camera is **not full screen** & **image looks little zoomed** .Camera takes only 80% of the screen

**What I tried**

I googled and came across many codes that give surety of full screen camera, but non works in my case

**My code**

camera_activity.xml

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

CameraActivity.java

```
private CameraPreview mPreview;
private FrameLayout cameraPreview;

cameraPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
mPreview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);
```

CameraPreview.java

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";
    private final List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        // supported preview sizes
        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for (Camera.Size str : mSupportedPreviewSizes)
            Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated fragment_setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // create the surface and start camera preview
            if (mCamera == null) {
                //mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(270);

                Camera.Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
                param.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
                mCamera.setParameters(param);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error fragment_setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new fragment_setting
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            /*mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();*/
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        refreshCamera(mCamera);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        //method to set a camera instance
        mCamera = camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // mCamera.release();

    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }

        float ratio;
        if (mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
        else
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

        // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview slightly
        setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
//        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);
    }

    private Camera.Size getBestPreviewSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result = null;

        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            if (size.width <= width && size.height <= height) {
                if (result == null) {
                    result = size;
                } else {
                    int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                    int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                    if (newArea > resultArea) {
                        result = size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return (result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add **getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);** in onCreate()-CameraActivity.java

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "Camera Activity";
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private FrameLayout cameraPreview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        try {
            cameraPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams=new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            mPreview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: doesn't made any difference :(